# OutputKeys.INDENT doesn't affect nodes, copied from another document

Tags: java, xml, dom

I read XML file into org.w3c.dom.Document, find a node by getElementsByTagName, append child from other document this way:

```
foundNode.appendChild(document.adoptNode(othersDocumentNode.cloneNode(true)));
```

After that I save result to a StringWriter:

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "20");
transformer.transform(
    new DOMSource(document),
    new StreamResult(out)
);
```

As a result I get document like this:

```
<document>
                   <foundNode>
<nestedContent>
  <content/>
</nestedContent>
                   </foundonde>
</document>
```

I.e. formatting doesn't affect nested content. I'd like all document to be formatted. How can I achieve this?

Thanx

Comment: Quite strange! Have you tried using `importNode()` instead of cloning and adopting the foreign node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The effect of output indentation is specified to be implementation defined. If you don't like the way one processor handles it, you can always try another (which in this case means, try Saxon).

Answer (score 0):

You will very likely find that the first child of <foundNode> is a text node containing nothing but a line break. Text nodes usually prevent the automatic indenter from doing its work, which consists of a) breaking lines and b) inserting the appropriate indentation. It does this, of course, by inserting a text node of its own, so one can see why indenters are usually written to refrain from indenting in the presence of existing text nodes.

But because the line break is preserved, it does **look** like the indenter has worked except that it's not honouring the indent width configuration.

What you can do to solve this problem depends a bit on the wider context of your task. For example, you could recursively trim whitespace text nodes from your nested content.

```
private static void removeWhitespace(Element el) {
    NodeList nl = el.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        Node n = nl.item(i);
        if (n.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            String text = n.getTextContent();
            String trimmed = text.trim();
            if (trimmed.isEmpty())
                el.removeChild(n);
            else if (trimmed.length() < text.length())
                n.setTextContent(trimmed);
        }
        if (n.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
            removeWhitespace((Element) n);
    }
}
```

(Note: This is just a primitive example. It works if you know that there isn't any payload data in text nodes.)

Calling [DocumentBuilderFactory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace%28boolean%29) when parsing the other document might look tempting on first sight, but do note the constraints described in the JavaDoc.